# Select visible rows after autofilering

Tags: vba, excel

I have autofiltered and I want to select rows which are not hidden, also if there is only one row I have to select only that row.

I'm stuck with a statement kindly help me out, the code is running but it is going to else statement even though the if statement is true, the code I have written is

```
If ActiveCell.Value ="" Then
Else
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" then 
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Loop
    Else
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xldown)).Select
    End if
    Selection.Copy
End if
```

Comment: What Scott said, but also, there should not be a space between Active and cell. Is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: ^ and `Entire row` should be `EntireRow`

Comment: Oops i have space in question but in my code it is not there

Comment: Please fix the code to be exactly what you have or you will get answers that do not help.

Comment: Sorry i was using mobile to post this my dictionary made this mess

Comment: I find that checking for length of 0 is better than trying to compare to an empty string. Try "If len(Active cell.offset(1,0).Value) = 0 then" This works for a cell with an empty string, and also for an empty cell (a different thing!)

Comment: Nope adding 0 did not work

Comment: Let me post my whole code

Comment: Why don't have edit option to post the whole code

Comment: @Zorro you should be able to edit your question by using the [edit] button.

Comment: If ActiveCell.Value ="" Then
Else
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    If Activecell.offset(1,0).Value = "" then 
        Do until Activecell.offset(1,0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Loop
    Else
        Range (Selection, selection.End(xldown)).Select
      End if
    Selection.Copy
End if

Comment: Wasn't able to post this code there so posted it here please help me

Comment: 1. You should be able to [edit]. 2. your code works fine I see no issues. For further help you should add a description **to your question** (by using [edit]) what your code actually does and what you expect it to do. A screenshot of your sheet and the address of the `ActiveCell` would be helpful too.

Comment: Check out my question now to know what i expect

Comment: I just want to know a way to select the rows after auto filtering

Answer (score 2):

To select every visible and non empty row in a worksheet use something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectVisibleNonEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Enter your worksheet name here

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range(ws.Rows(2), ws.Rows(lastRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If i want to run this code many times in a macro should i change the variable name or is there a code to clear the values after each time it is run

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can run this sub as many times as you like to.

Comment: I want to filter one type and paste it in one sheet and another type and paste it in corresponding sheet and so on each time should i write sub and i want to run macro in only one run

Comment: Sorry, but this site cannot teach you how to code VBA. You should at least know how to call a Sub from anther one.

Comment: Ok thanks though I'll do some research, this is my 2nd day trying VBA , i don't even know coding , not even from a computers background

Comment: No problem, but then this might be the wrong site for you and you better look for a forum where someone can guide you. This site is question/answer based and used for specific programming questions.

Comment: Peh when i ran the above code while filtering but there was no data related to that filer so this code copied the heading itself , how do i fix this